# pg_dumpall > alldb.sql output bash: alldb.sql: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

Im trying to take all backup by running these as superuser i.e postgres but

```
pg_dumpall > alldb.sql

bash: alldb.sql: Permission denied
```

pg_dumpall works but give backup as text in terminal

made changes in pg_hba.conf

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbT1j.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `pg_dumpall` or `pg_hba`. It is just **the shell** complaining that it cannot write to the current directory. Try another directory to put your file into, for example:

```
 pg_dumpall > /tmp/alldb.sql
```